# How to recursively re-compress multiple archive types into 7zip on Linux?

Tags: linux, archive, 7zip, compression

I have a directory with quite a few sub directories and in these directories are archives of various types (zip, rar, 7zip, tar.gz, etc.).  I would like to go through the directory and all of the sub directories extracting each archive and re-compressing it as a 7zip.